Google AppSheet: Handling API Errors and Providing Real-Time User Feedback
I'm currently working on an AppSheet app that submits data via a form to a Google Sheet.
It's set up in the way AppSheet appears to have intended: the data source is Google Sheets with specific columns, the users are able to submit data via a form view. This works as intended - a new record is added. From there, an automation is triggered (on adding a new row to our sheet), which sends this data to an external API, which then processes the submission and updates our backend system. The integration is working well overall.
However, I’m running into an issue with handling errors from the API and providing real-time feedback to the user. Specifically:

If the API returns an error (e.g., 500 server error) or if the user attempts an action that is "illegal" (based on the API logic), there’s currently no way for the user to know that something went wrong.

Since the API call is handled by an automation after the data is submitted to the Google Sheet, the user doesn’t receive immediate feedback. They assume everything went fine, even if the API failed.


I'm trying to figure out a way to:

Notify the user in real-time if the API submission failed or was rejected.

Display a status (e.g., "Success," "Failed," "Pending") in the AppSheet app after the form is submitted, based on the response from the API.


I've tried:

Adding a status column in the Google Sheet to be updated based on the API response, but this doesn’t seem to provide real-time feedback in the app, as the column is updated after some time by an automation, possibly after being read by AppSheet.

Redirecting users to an intermediary view that could show the status, but integrating the API response into this flow in real-time is challenging. Also, again - there are no guarantees that it will be displayed after it gets updated and not before.

Using some automation configuration magic: I suppose I could just send a notification to the user that he submitted invalid data - but is that my only option?


Has anyone tackled a similar issue or found a creative workaround to handle API errors and provide real-time feedback to the user within AppSheet? Any advice, suggestions, or best practices would be greatly appreciated!
